# JQuery mobile -Edit Listview and count bubbles with Popup

Tags: jquery, mobile, dynamic, count, popup

I wanna make List which is there is Count Bubbles in it,
but the count bubbles is Dynamic,
So I mean when the list is clicked, the popup will be shown and asking The value, if we input the value and click "Ok" button, the value of count bubble automatically will change....
here is the code

---

```
<ul id="list" data-role="listview"  data-inset="true"  data-theme="e" data-divider-theme="b">

<li data-filtertext="ayam, goreng"><a href="#popupQTY" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-inline="true" data-transition="flow">List 1 <span class='ui-li-count'>1</span></a> </li>
<li data-filtertext="ayam, penyet"><a href="#popupQTY" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-inline="true" data-transition="flow">List 2 <span class='ui-li-count'>2</span></a></li>
<li data-filtertext="ayam, bakar" ><a href="#popupQTY" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-inline="true" data-transition="flow">List 3 <span class='ui-li-count'>3</span></a></li>
<li data-filtertext="ayam, guling"><a href="#popupQTY" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-inline="true" data-transition="flow">List 4 <span class='ui-li-count'>4</span></a></li>
```

---

this is for pop up

```
div data-role="popup" id="popupQTY" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all">

    <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>           

        <form>
            <div style="padding:10px 20px;">
              <h3>Please input the Quantity</h3>
              <label for="un" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Qty :</label>
              <input type="number" name="qty" id="QTY" value="1" placeholder="qty" data-theme="a" />

              <a href="#" id="setQty" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-transition="flow">Ok</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/idam/mAdDN/

---

help me how make it with JavaScript code or JQuery... 
thanks before ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified version of your
[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ugdy31hu/)

basically what you should do is assgin `id` to each bubble `<span>` then open the popup programmatically using `$( "#popup" ).popup( "open", options);`, when click on the ok button, update the `<span>` with the `id` using `$('#id').text(quantity)`